# Issue in using ISNUMBER SEARCH to find text values over a range of multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have created a formula that searches a single cell for any words from a predefined list and if the word is present, a "Yes" is output. This is working fine however I now need it to search a range of cells for these values and this is resulting in a negative result.

The formula itself is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Drug effects","Drug therapy","antagonist"},C2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

This will successfully search cell C2 for those values and will output "Yes" if found. Similarly, if I update it to search D2 and it also contains those values, a "Yes" will also appear - all of this is expected and correct.

The issue I'm having is that I want it to search both C2 and D2 and give a "Yes" if a search term is found in either 1 or both of those cells. The formula I'm using is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Drug effects","Drug therapy","antagonist"},C2:D2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

This is resulting in a "No" and it shouldn't since the value is present in both C2 and D2. Can anyone offer a suggestion to get this formula working over a range of cells?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, not end-user questions. As such your question is off-topic here and should be posted in an appropriate end-user forum (e.g. MS Answers, SuperUser).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `{"Drug effects","Drug therapy","antagonist"}` and `C2:D2` are both *horizontal* vectors and Excel does not know how to calculate that as an array formula. I can get your formula to work by making the first array *vertical* by either

(a) using semicolons instead of commas to separate the array elements:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Drug effects";"Drug therapy";"antagonist"},C2:D2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

or

(b) by using `TRANSPOSE`:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE({"Drug effects","Drug therapy","antagonist"}),C2:D2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

This will work as long as your search range `C2:D2` is 1-dimensional and horizontal. For 1-dimensional and vertical you can apply `TRANSPOSE` to the search range, e.g.:

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Drug effects";"Drug therapy";"antagonist"},TRANSPOSE(C2:C3))))>0,"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Simply switching from a comma to a semi-colon worked perfectly - thanks so much for your help